# Converting different maximum scores to percentage out of 100

Tags: r, dataset

I have three different datasets with 3 students and 3 subjects each, with different maximum scores(125,150,200). How to calculate the mean percentage(out of 100) per subject of a standard(not section), when all the three maximum scores are different. which are not comparable at this point.

```
Class2:
section1.csv

      english        maths        science
name  score(125)   score(125)  score(125)
 sam    114          112           111
 erm    89           91            97
 asd    101         107           118


section2.csv

      english        maths        science
name  score(150)   score(150)  score(150)
 wer    141          127           143
 rahul  134           119            145
 rohit  149          135            139



section3.csv

        english        maths        science
name    score(200)   score(200)  score(200)
 vinod    178          186           176
 manoj    189          191           185
 deepak   191          178           187
```

P.s: Expected columns in the  output:

`class1  englishavg  mathsavg  scienceavg`( the values are the summation of mean percentage of all the three section)

Here is the piece of the code. I tried.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv") ## creates a vector with all file names in your folder

list_files  <- lapply(files,read.csv,header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)

list_files  <- lapply(list_files, function(x) x)

engav  <- sapply(list_files,function(x) mean(as.numeric(x[,2]),na.rm=T)/2)
mathav   <- sapply(list_files,function(x) mean(as.numeric(x[,3]),na.rm=T)/2)
scienceav   <- sapply(list_files,function(x) mean(as.numeric(x[,4]),na.rm=T)/2)


result  <- cbind(files,engav,mathav,scienceav)
```

Looking forward for an assistance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Users of this community are expected to put own efford into their research before posting. Please add what you have tried and describe what does not work. People here are no (and don't like to be a) code writing service

Comment: sounds like you're looking for `?prop.table`